# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to get count of rows based null value on one specific column. I have used the given below code. Here cad assign column contains values and  also null values. I have to count how many null values on cad_assign, and based on that I have to display values.

```
protected void ddlCircle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter cd;
    cd = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = cd.GetAvailableData(ddlCircle.SelectedValue);// dt get values where cad_assign is null

    int x;
    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
      list.Add(dtrow); // here we getting dt count. 
    }
    x = Convert.ToInt32(list); // error popup here
}
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT state1, district, site_id, site_name
FROM tbl_site_details
WHERE (state1 = @state1) AND (cad_assign IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is that you're trying to convert an `ArrayList` to an `Int32` (`Convert.ToInt32` doesn't count a list, it tries to convert the given object to an integer).

If you're trying to count the list, you can use `ArrayList.Count`:

```
x = list.Count;
```

You can take it one step easier and not use a list and directly take a count of the rows:

```
x = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Or even better change your SQL to return the count directly:

```
SELECT Count(1)
FROM tbl_site_details
WHERE (state1 = @state1) AND (cad_assign IS NULL)
```

I'm not sure how exactly you would fetch a scalar result using your ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters, but you should be able to do this at least:

```
var x = (int)dt.Rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` implements `ICollection` and therefore will have a `.Count` property as well as Linq extension methods.

if you want the overall count

```
x = list.Count;
```

for the null count

```
x = list.Count(a => a == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are converting list of integer values to int, thats not possible.

```
x = list.Count;
```

Comment: Based on the question, this is not what he was looking for